# What does 'made him right away' mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> Then he was in line for a teller, smacking himself on the thigh with
>   his rolled-up Herald. this was something a sweaty-eyed arsonist did,
>   returning to the scene of the crime. A whiff of bleach hit him, even
>   if it was present only in his mind.
>    “Oh, hi.” **She made him
>   right away**, Jesus Christ, this skinny-necked black teller with her
>   hair flour-sacked on top of her head, smiling. “Haven’t seen you for a
>   while. Meter change, right?”
>
> -- Chuck Hogan, The Town

The highlighted part seems to mean either of these: (1) she recognized him as soon as he neared the counter of her; (2) she made him ready right away. What does the phrase mean?

Comment: Use of "made" in similar case implies identifying someone. Generally even after some kind of disguise or a situation where it is hard to identify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of word "made" in this case is not a formal one but instead a slang.

Defition form [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/make).

> Make: (Slang) **Identification of a person or thing**, often from information in police records: Did you get a make on the thief?

So in this case "made him right away" means "recognized/identified him right away."

Comment: It's interesting that the definition and example sentence in TFD mention law enforcement and criminality, and the passage in the book is about an arsonist. I wonder if using _make_ to mean _identify_ wouldn't be such a good idea in other circles. I know it's slang I haven't heard very often, but then I again, I try to stay out of trouble :^)

Answer (score 2):

I think the former one fits in this context of **identifying a person** whom she hasn't met for quite some time.

As you identified *[right away](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/RIGHTAWAY)* correctly,

> Right away (adv.) - Without delay or hesitation; with no time intervention.